# Get all text contents of a DOM element outside its children using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a DOM element that has some number of children, interleaved by text strings.
I want to get each of these text strings, and replace them using regex.
For example:

```
<div>Text started.
<a>Link child inside</a>
Some more text. 
<u>Another child</u>
Closing text.</div>
```

In this example, I want to extract the strings "Text started.", "Some more text.", and "Closing text.", so that I can replace each of them later with something else.

The solution should be generic since the number of children inside the parent can vary, and the node types as well.

Anyone got a clever answer to achieve this easily using javascript?

Comment: Are you displaying your records i.e `"Text started.", "Some more text.", and "Closing text.", ` manually in the child html? or is it configured automatically through JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `childNodes` to check if the `nodeType` is a text node.
Doing this inside a `forEach` you can easily replace the text with whatever you want.

Example:

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div').item(0);

[].slice.call(div.childNodes).forEach(function(node , i) {
  if(node.nodeType === 3) {
    var currNode = div.childNodes[i];
    var currText = div.childNodes[i].textContent;
    currNode.textContent = currText.replace(/text/i, ' Foo');
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  Text started.
  <a>Link child inside</a>
  Some more text. 
  <u>Another child</u>
  Closing text.
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't notice the difference between the "children" and "childNodes" property before. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, have fun. ; )

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows;

```js
var textNodes = [...test.childNodes].filter(child => child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
textNodes.forEach(tn => console.log(tn.textContent))
```

```html
<div id="test">Text started.
<a>Link child inside</a>
Some more text. 
<u>Another child</u>
Closing text.</div>
```